# Unrecognized selector sent to instance (self.navigationController.toolbar)

Tags: iphone, toolbar, pushviewcontroller

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 2 days with it - and I need help.

In my controller, I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    ... // the rest of initialisation goes here
}
```

This controller presents details of one item selected from the list.  Controller displaying a list of items does `pushViewControllerAnimated` on this controller to display details of the item selected by the user.

This works fine on the first execution, however when the user presses back button - and then selects another (or even the same) item from the list, line `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]` causes `SIGABRT` with this stack trace:

```
2011-11-04 10:24:21.423 OOKL[32026:10403] -[NSCFNumber view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69db0e0
2011-11-04 10:24:21.426 OOKL[32026:10403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69db0e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019875a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01adb313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x019890bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x018f8966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x018f8522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0063223e -[UIToolbar setItems:animated:] + 1554
    6   UIKit                               0x005f8ccb -[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerContextualToolbar) setToolbarItems:] + 49
    7   OOKL                                0x0003df87 -[OOExplorerObjectDetailController setUpToolbarForExplore] + 1335
    8   OOKL                                0x0003eb2b -[OOExplorerObjectDetailController viewDidLoad] + 2043
    9   UIKit                               0x005fd089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    10  UIKit                               0x005fb482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    11  UIKit                               0x0060bf25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    12  UIKit                               0x0060a555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x0060b870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    14  UIKit                               0x0060632a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    15  UIKit                               0x0060d562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    16  UIKit                               0x006061c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    17  OOKL                                0x0002ed8b -[OOExploreController showObjectDetailControllerWithObject:] + 571
    18  OOKL                                0x0002da1c -[OOExploreController parserDidFinish:] + 316
    19  OOKL                                0x00021c13 -[OOXMLParser parserDidEndDocument:] + 99
    20  Foundation                          0x00385717 _endDocument + 95
    21  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x02ad4215 xmlParseChunk + 7380
    22  Foundation                          0x0038615a -[NSXMLParser parse] + 321
    23  OOKL                                0x00021893 -[OOXMLParser parseString:] + 339
    24  OOKL                                0x0002d8d5 -[OOExploreController parseXml:] + 165
    25  OOKL                                0x0002d81f -[OOExploreController requestDidFinishLoading:] + 79
    26  OOKL                                0x00011cba -[OOSharedSeverController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 298
    27  Foundation                          0x002ef112 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
    28  Foundation                          0x002ef06b _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
    29  CFNetwork                           0x013cd48e _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 220
    30  CFNetwork                           0x014986e1 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 293
    31  CFNetwork                           0x013c3c80 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    32  CFNetwork                           0x013c3acf _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x019688ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x018c688b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x018c5d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x018c5840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x018c5761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x01e601c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x01e60289 GSEventRun + 115
    40  UIKit                               0x0055bc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    41  OOKL                                0x00002d09 main + 121
    42  OOKL                                0x00002c85 start + 53
)
```

I thought, maybe, I should setup `self.toolbarItems` first before making the toolbar visible - but then I get this same error when I do

```
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray ...]
```

I'm desperate now - any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: Now for some reason I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` instead of `SIGABRT` - in the same place - and no stack trace is produced at all.

Comment: Have you notice that your code try to call the method view on an instance of NSCFNumber?

Comment: This is not crashed due to view traversing. I think you need to check  imported/exported delegate's feasibility. It might be possible to release mistakenly.

Comment: Your EDIT suggests that you are trying to access an object which has been released already and doesn't exists. Try fixing breakpoints.

Comment: @LucaBernardi: Hm! Very strange indeed!  Where can this be happening?  And why would it work the first time, but not the second time around?  Could there be something strange happening with the toolbar?

Comment: Can you show [OOExplorerObjectDetailController setUpToolbarForExplore] ?

Comment: @ElanthiraiyanS: I sorted the part int the edit - I had a typo in my "autorelease", which caused it.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.  Not sure how this code got there, but, for some reason I had `[button autorelease]` after creating it before adding it into the array.  Then I also had `[button release]` in the `dealloc`.  I guess, the two things together were causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the stack trace tells:

> -[NSCFNumber view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69db0e0

You are accidentally overreleasing something that is leading to this message sent to some dangling pointer (reference to some junk).

Check if you are releasing your navigationController, ViewController or anything where your workflow begins.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it's pretty much what the problem was - "overreleasing something". For some reason I had [button autorelease] after creating it before adding it into the array. Then I also had [button release] in the dealloc. I guess, the two things together were causing problems.